# A determinant similar to the Vandermonde'a determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, determinant, hankel-matrices

$$ \det\begin{bmatrix}
s_0&s_1&s_2&\cdots&s_{n-1}\\
s_1&s_2&s_3&\cdots&s_n\\
s_2&s_3&s_4&\cdots&s_{n+1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
s_{n-1}&s_n&s_{n+1}&\cdots&s_{2n-2}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $$s_k = x_1^k + x_2^k + \dots + x_n^k $$

I solved the task. I used Cauchy's theorem on the determinant of the product. Let the above matrix be A.

$\det(A) = \det(BC) = \det(B)  \det (C)$, where C is Vandermonde matrix and B it's a transposition. So, the determinant is Vandermonde determinant to the power of 2. Can someone check my reasoning?

Comment: This is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix

Comment: The link you provided should answer your question - where are you stuck when trying to apply what you see there?

Comment: Yes i post my solution

Comment: Your solution is correct. And no, the fact that it is a Hankel matrix is not very useful.